# Ubuntu update error？

Tags: apt, upgrade

```
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I want to upgrade the system，An error occurred while updating the software, can I continue to upgrade the system? 16 upgrade to 18

```
    df -Th | grep -v fs
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     ext4       97G   97G     0 100% /
```

Comment: The IO error is pretty clear: you're out of disk space ...

Comment: You've got no space to upgrade.  Are you sure you're on Ubuntu Core 16, as it upgrades differently to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for example (The *year* systems are different products to the *year.month* Ubuntu systems)

Comment: Do I need to add a disk?

Comment: Your OS & release is unclear; Ubuntu has used *year* format releases for *snap* only products since 2016, where an upgrade from 16 to 18 does not alter any programs; only the base OS itself is updated (as *snap* packages are the same for all releases).  In comparison a 16.04 system needs to also not only the base, but all applications as well thus more space is required. Either way - you're out of disk space and that issue needs resolution first.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Will the function of Apache and some plugins be changed?

Comment: No, you don't need to "add a disk".  You need to manage the space on `/`. Start with `sudo du -sk /* | sort -rn | less`. Remember: you can remove logs, data, backups, ... but NOT binaries. You have to find the package providing the binary. Use `dpkg -S filename` to do so.

Comment: These can't be deleted